# Infix call on <this> not working

Tags: scala

Why does the following not work? Does Scala disallow an infix call on a scoped method at the beginning of an expression?

```
class Foo {
  def foo(x: String) = 1
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  val bar1 = foo("42")      // compiles
  val bar2 = this foo "42"  // compiles
  val bar3 = foo "42"       // does not compile
}
```

Comment: If you write it `foo "42"`, it's not an infix call. It would be a *prefix* call, except Scala doesn't have prefix call (except for `unary_-` and 3 others).

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @sjrd, `foo "42"` is not an infix call. In an infix call, the operator must be infixed *between* the two objects. i.e., have the form:

```
<object1> <operator> <object2>
```

`foo "42"` is a prefix call. i.e., has the form:

```
<operator> <object>
```

In Scala, prefix calls are limited to `+`, `-`, `!` or `~` according to the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#prefix-operations):

> A prefix operation op;e consists of a prefix operator op, which must be one of the identifiers **‘+’, ‘-’, ‘!’ or ‘~’**. The expression op;e is equivalent to the postfix method application e.unary_op.

This is why `this foo "42"` works, but `foo "42"` does not.

Comment: Understood. Writing a DSL in Scala is nice, but the strictness on "infix" makes it a bit hard. Basically, a DSL "expression" is always a chain of obj (infix param)* (postfix). It would be nicer to also chain postfix operations.